# IntelliJ (Rider and IDEA) connect to JIRA task server using OAuth2 and Two Factor verification

Tags: intellij-idea, oauth, jira, two-factor-authentication

I would like to connect to my JIRA tasks from IntelliJ Rider (and IDEA). The JIRA server enables only OAuth2 authentication via login.microsoftonline.com, which requires credentials + second factor authentication (DUO).

Is there a way how to connect to the JIRA server from IntelliJ?

Miro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible at the moment: [IDEA-149504](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149504).